# mysql: select query multiple condition of same column not working with having

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want do search with filter system like amazon, ebay or Souq.
this table have all values and keys for all products "go_products_cats_options" and this `pco_option_id` IN(41, 31, 32, 30)
is key of filter and this numbers `pco_answer_id` IN('312', '250', '253', '240') is values of this keys

and i want search in this keys and values not with OR but with AND
this my statement so what can i do

```
   SELECT
        `go_products`.*,
        `go_users`.`u_username`,
        `go_users`.`u_id`
    FROM
        `go_products`
    INNER JOIN `go_users` ON `go_users`.`u_id` = `go_products`.`product_store_id`
    INNER JOIN `go_products_cats_options` ON `go_products_cats_options`.`pco_product_id` = `go_products`.`product_id`
    WHERE
        `go_users`.`u_is_active` = 1 AND `go_users`.`u_store_is_expire` = 0 AND `go_products`.`product_cat_id` IN('39') AND `product_active` = 1 AND(
            `pco_option_id` IN(41, 31, 32, 30) AND `pco_answer_id` IN('312', '250', '253', '240')
        )
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 4
    ORDER BY
        `product_id` ASC
    LIMIT 40
```

and when i used having not working successfully

Comment: Specify the error text or image also.

Comment: Your `HAVING` clause does not make much sense in the absence of a `GROUP BY` aggregation.  Please tell us what your query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: i want do search with filter system like amazon, ebay or Souq.
this table have all values and keys for all products "go_products_cats_options" and this `pco_option_id` IN(41, 31, 32, 30)
is key of filter and this numbers `pco_answer_id` IN('312', '250', '253', '240') is values of this keys

and i want search in this keys and values not with OR but with AND

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i can't understand youn Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prepare a statement without group by. Group by clause is required before having keyword. You can use :

```
SELECT 

    `go_products`.*,
    `go_users`.`u_username`,
    `go_users`.`u_id`
FROM
    `go_products`
INNER JOIN `go_users` ON `go_users`.`u_id` = `go_products`.`product_store_id`
INNER JOIN `go_products_cats_options` ON `go_products_cats_options`.`pco_product_id` = `go_products`.`product_id`
WHERE
    `go_users`.`u_is_active` = 1 AND `go_users`.`u_store_is_expire` = 0 AND `go_products`.`product_cat_id` IN('39') AND `product_active` = 1 AND(
        `pco_option_id` IN(41, 31, 32, 30) AND `pco_answer_id` IN('312', '250', '253', '240')
    )
GROUP BY u_username
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 4
ORDER BY
    `product_id` ASC
LIMIT 40
```